# Мне надо удалить 3 элемента из статического массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Смотрите, у меня, допустим, есть 10 элементов в массиве. Я хочу удалить k элементов  из любого места. Пусть это будут элементы с 3 по 5, но надо сделать так, чтобы они сдвинулись дальше и потом просто не поместились. Понимаю, может для понимания сложно, но если есть вопросы задавайте.
Ниже прилагаю свой вариант кода, что пытался сделать.

```
void remove(int ar[],const int n)
{
    int t;      
    int size=n; 
    int num;
    int nomer1;
    cout << "Viberite s kakogo 4isla vi hotite ydalit':";
    cin >> num;
    cout << "Viberite po kakoe 4islo vi hotite ydalit':";
    cin >> nomer1;
    cout << endl;   
    size = size - (nomer1 - num);
    for (int i = num; i < nomer1 + 1; i++) {
        ar[i] = ar[i++];
         cout << ar[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 1; i < size + 1; i++)
        {
            cout << ar[i] << " ";
        }
}
```

Увы, выводит вот так, а мне надо, чтоб 3 элемент(пятерка, стал единицей, единица соответственно 10 и так далее)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUohY.png]

Comment: У Вас статический массив? Возьмите вектор и там удаляйте что хотите и как хотите

Comment: В этом и фишка моего вопроса, что я не должен использовать векторы, я просто должен выйти за пределы size и не выводить их.

Comment: выйти за size? удачи) В Вашем вопросе нету "фишки" - не пилите велосипед, учите stl, экономьте свое время и пишите код)

Comment: Да, там получится мусор, но мы его не выводим.

Comment: А что значит - "Пусть это будут элементы с 3 по 5, но надо сделать так, чтобы они сдвинулись дальше и потом просто не поместились" - Вы хоть Сами понимаете что хотите и вообще как в абстракции памяти это все будет? Куда не поместились?

Comment: приведите несколько примеров вхрдных и выходных данных

Comment: Раз удалить, значит удалить (с концами). Просто перепишите на их место k последних и скорректируйте на k переменную, в которой храните текущее количество элементов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сдвигать нужно все элементы после удаляемых, а не только те, что встают на их место. За это отвечают пределы первого цикла for. Кроме того, подкорректировал на нумерацию с нуля и поправил число удаляемых. Корректность введённых индексов не проверяется.

```
void remove(int ar[], const int n)
{
    int t;
    int size = n;
    int istart, iend, numdel;
    int nomer1;
    std::cout << "Viberite s kakogo indexa vi hotite ydalit':";
    std::cin >> istart;
    std::cout << "Viberite po kakoy index vi hotite ydalit':";
    std::cin >> iend;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    numdel = iend - istart + 1;
    size = size - numdel;
    for (int i = istart; i < size; i++) {
        ar[i] = ar[i + numdel];
        std::cout << ar[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << ar[i] << " ";
    }

}

int ar[10] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    remove(ar, 10);

------------
Viberite s kakogo indexa vi hotite ydalit':3
Viberite po kakoy index vi hotite ydalit':5

6 7 8 9
0 1 2 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Свопайте нужные вам элементы с теми что в конце и возвращайте новый размер массива, уменьшенный на количество удаленных элементов.

Comment: Как то на удаление это не смахивает...... а как насчет кейса с int arr[N]; sizeof(arr); ? Массив то на стеке)

Comment: А какое вы себе представляете удаление? подменять символ и указывать им на новое место на стеке в которое будет скопировано только то что нужно автору?

Comment: работать с кучей, стек не для таких вещей